# Google Analytics - Showing multiple site stats at once

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way in google analytics to add multiple sites to and show all the stats together? So like the graphs and total visits/unique hits all combined for all the sites added to the google analytics account?

For example if I have:

site1.com
site2.com
site3.com

Under one google analytics account, is there a way in google analytics tool to merge them together so I can see a sum of all traffic in one report?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033876) on the analytics help system should help you. (Updated Feb 2013 with latest link).

Comment: Paul isnt that article more geared on when a user travels across domains?

Comment: Yes, that's the tricky part of the process. Telling google to use two domains is straightforward, what you don't want is to count clicks between the domains as if they were exiting the site.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a service ( [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) ) which utilizes the Google Analytics API and allows you to create charts and then embed them into websites.  Recently we just added support for "multi-domain" charts (if you do check it out, just make a chart using the "Wizard" and then you have the option of adding additional domains/profiles).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do it historically, but for the future, I think if you just use the same embedded code on each site it will do that.  I discovered this by accident :P

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to merge your historical data from multiple GA properties.  What you can do in the future is use the same exact GA code on multiple sites to 'merge the data'.   If you take this route and later want to view your data on a per domain basis: you will either need to write your own custom filters to be able to filter out your data by domain name (you can do this any time), or you should add a custom dimension or variable (have to do this now) so you can tag each pageview with the domain of your choice.   I would use custom variables for this, which makes reporting a lot easier.

You might also want to take a different approach.
1. Create a property for each individual site, so that each site has its own reporting in GA.
2. Create a new property called "all sites" and then use that on every site as well.

You can search google and find more information on using multiple trackers.  Its very easy to do via javascript.  Having multiple trackers will allow you to go to the "all-sites" property to view everything, and if you need to view things on a site per site basis then you can do that with each site's own property.   Multiple Trackers are commonly used for affiliate programs, or sites that allow users to create their own pages (something like a tumblr or myspace) because they allow GA to fire data to multiple properties which dont always have to be in the same GA account.