# Google Analytics and multiple sites with combined stats

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, multiple-domains

I have about 40 sites (similar structure just different verticals/content). Example: site1.com site2.com

**Is it possible to see the stats of all sites within one property?**

I was thinking of doing this in Google Analytics:

- Create a new analytics account
- Create a new property
- Create a profile for every site within the single property

The default property Google creates is named "All Web Site Data". Does this mean that I can see combined statistics for all sites under this single property. Going on the other properties I would see the stats for the individual site.

What I described above... is there a special analytics tracking code I need to put on my sites?

There was [a similar question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10012/google-analytics-showing-multiple-site-stats-at-once) asked but the link in the answer is now dead.